# Weird Intellisense and code suggestions bug VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am having a weird bug on vscode for which the auto-completion suggestion shows twice and on the first auto-completion, the cursor is not going to the end of the word. I tried to check and play around with autocompletion settings but can't manage to solve this.
One thing I noticed is that if I open the suggestion menu manually and then select it, it works, this happens with the quick suggestions menu.
See the video below for clarity. This is a really annoying issue, can't find anything online about it.

[See video here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ffmW.gif)

Answer (score 1):

**Possible solutions**:

1. Update your vscode if available.
2. If that only happens when writing CSS code, maybe that's an extension related issue.

See if that works :)